# Comparing the hash value of data copied on system clipboard and pasted in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, clipboard, hashcode

I need some technical advice on a issue. The scenario is like this. if there is some text copied from Excel or any application for that matter on to system clipboard and later pasted at some point in time (assuming contents f system clipboard were not changed), can we compare hash of the value copied ( hash value is already stored when data was copied in a hash table in the application the data was copied from) to the hash value of the contents of system clipboard ( the one available when paste action is performed)? I just want to make sure if these two values were exactly the same and came from the same application.

can someone make my understanding more clear and suggest something?

Thanks.

Comment: You always can hash a string, just use the md5 hash and compare them, but as it's going to be a string just compare those strings. The problem is to know from where the data came, you can't know which program did put the data inside the clipboard, at least I don't know any way, maybe if you explain why do you want to do that there can be an alternative solution.

Comment: @Gusman Do not ever use md5 ...

Comment: @Bogdan could you explain why or post a link, otherwise your comment is worthless

Comment: @reggaeguitar Google md5, click first link - read paragraph 3 ...

Comment: @all : yes, I am already using Md5. but as I stated in response to the answer below I need to know if the same application written that value not any other application.

Comment: @Bogdan this matters for cryptographic issues, but in this case the hash algorithm is being used to generate something like an unique identifier of data, so there is no problem at all.

Comment: @Shaktisaxena if the data is exactly the same posted from your app, what matters if another app has posted it (i'm asking to try understand your problem)?

Comment: @Gusman md5 is not ok for cryptography and cryptographic hashes are not good for generating uniques ids(they are designed to be slow to compute) ...

Comment: @Bogdan so, which hash algorithm do you use to hash an string with low collission possibilities like md5? (please don't tell me CRC32 XD).

Comment: @Gusman In this specific case String.GetHashCode() should be ok. In a more general case you can take a look at non-cryptpographic hash functions on wikipedia - my personal favorite is pearson hashing.

Comment: Very interesting @Bogdan, I'm going to add it to my utils lib, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Added to show how to hash (too long for comments), don't think of it as a full response

To hash an string you can use this:

```
    public static string HashMD5(string input)
    {

        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();

        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Hi,  Thanks. but I already have this in place in my application. I fear if any other application places the same value on to the clipboard, the hash value would still be the same when compared in my application. we need to somehow know where this data came from.

Comment: @Shaktisaxena There is no way to determine what application put the data in clipboard from another application ...

Comment: @Bogdan: I know there is no way atleast on windows to get to know where this data came from unlike X11 which can give you information about the application name too.